# ms access create form with vba

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

bfollowing data structure:

table categories: ID | description

table questiontypes: ID | description [text, boolean, single choice]

table questions: ID | categoryID | questiontypeID | description

table partQuestAnswer: ID | participantNumber | questionID | answerID

Now I want to create a form (not manually, there are around 180 questions...)

It should look like this: for each question in each category it should show the question description (the question itself), an input field depending on the questiontype (5 radio buttons in a group for single choice, a checkbox for boolean, a textfield for text).

Is there a way to create the form via vba in access 2010? Where and how can I do this?

And how can I put the gathered data correctly in my partQuestAnswer table?